# Custom post type in Wordpress - can't get meta box's to show

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have managed to get the "Vehicle Manager" section to load on the left so I can create the custom post type, but I can't get the meta box's to show to enter the custom information for that post type (if that makes sense).

Here is my vehicle-manager.php:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'vehicle_manager_register');
function vehicle_manager_register()
{
    //Arguments to create post type.
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Vehicle Manager'),
        'singular_label' => __('Vehicle'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'vehicles',
            'with_front' => false
        )
    );
    //Register type and custom taxonomy for type.
    register_post_type('vehicle', $args);
    register_taxonomy("vehicle-type", array(
        "vehicles"
    ), array(
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "label" => "Vehicle Types",
        "singular_label" => "Vehicle Type",
        "rewrite" => true,
        "slug" => 'vehicle-type'
    ));
}
//Begin custom fields
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    set_post_thumbnail_size(220, 150);
    add_image_size('storefront', 800, 600, true);
}
add_action("admin_init", "vehicle_manager_add_meta");
function vehicle_manager_add_meta()
{
    add_meta_box("vehicle-meta", "Vehicle Options", "vehicle_manager_meta_options", "vehicles", "normal", "high");
}
//Start of actual custom fields
function vehicle_manager_meta_options()
{
    global $post;
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;
    $custom  = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $make    = $custom["make"][0];
    $model   = $custom["model"][0];
    $year    = $custom["year"][0];
    $mileage = $custom["mileage"][0];
    $engine  = $custom["engine"][0];
    $colour  = $custom["colour"][0];
    $price   = $custom["price"][0];
    $uspa    = $custom["uspa"][0];
    $uspb    = $custom["uspb"][0];
    $uspc    = $custom["uspc"][0];
?>
<style type="text/css">
<?php
    include('vehicle-manager.css');
?>
</style>
<div class="vehicle_manager_extras">
<div><label>Make:</label><input name="make"
value="<?php
    echo $make;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Model</label><input name="model"
value="<?php
    echo $model;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Year:</label><input name="year"
value="<?php
    echo $year;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Miles:</label><input name="miles"
value="<?php
    echo $miles;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Engine:</label><input name="engine"
value="<?php
    echo $engine;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Colour:</label><input name="colour"
value="<?php
    echo $colour;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Price:</label><input name="price"
value="<?php
    echo $price;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Feature 1 (optional):</label><input name="uspa"
value="<?php
    echo $uspa;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Feature 2 (optional):</label><input name="uspb"
value="<?php
    echo $uspb;
?>" /></div>
<div><label>Feature 3 (optional):</label><input name="uspc"
value="<?php
    echo $uspc;
?>" /></div>
</div>
<?php
}
add_action('save_post', 'business_manager_save_extras');
function business_manager_save_extras()
{
    global $post;
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        //if you remove this the sky will fall on your head.
        return $post_id;
    } else {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "make", $_POST["make"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "model", $_POST["model"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "year", $_POST["year"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "miles", $_POST["miles"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "engine", $_POST["engine"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "colour", $_POST["colour"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $_POST["price"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "uspa", $_POST["uspa"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "uspb", $_POST["uspb"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "uspc", $_POST["uspc"]);
    }
}
```

Here is functions.php:

```
<?php
require_once('vehicle-manager.php');
define('TEMPPATH', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'));
define('IMAGES', TEMPPATH . "/images");
add_theme_support('nav-menus');
if (function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'main' => 'Main Nav'
    ));
}
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Primary Sidebar', 'primary-sidebar'),
        'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
        'description' => __('The primary widget area', 'dir'),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => "</div>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
}
16;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're registering your metabox with a posttype `vehicles` [(4th argument)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box):

```
add_meta_box("vehicle-meta", "Vehicle Options", "vehicle_manager_meta_options", "vehicles", "normal", "high");
```

While you register your posttype as `vehicle` [(1st argument)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type):

```
register_post_type('vehicle', $args);
```

Your taxonomy shouldn't show up either as you enable it for `vehicles` as well instead of `vehicle`:

```
register_taxonomy("vehicle-type", array(
        "vehicles"
    ), array( ... ));
```

(Also: please try to keep your code as minimal as possible, omitting unrelated sections (i.e. the sidebar stuff))

Answer (score 0):

You're recording the post_type with the name of "**vehicle**".

In the taxonomy you must register with post_type "**vehicle**" no "vehicles".

The custom target must also register with the post_type "**vehicle**" no "vehicles".